# List of Queries for each Badge

Tags: discussion, badges, data-explorer

For people "in the know", do we have queries on the Data Explorer which exactly match the criteria for specific badges?

For example, we have an [Unsung Hero tracker](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/345/how-unsung-am-i).  But, like all similar queries, I wonder if it accurately represents the badge or if it's missing a few key points.

Or would revealing this information lead to too much "gaming the system"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some badges, like *Unsung Hero*, are pretty hard to impossible to game: how do you ensure that 25% of your answers are accepted and never up-voted? An *Unsung Hero* query is pretty easy to confirm as accurate, too (the one you linked looks like it is).

For others, particularly ones that are easy to game, the data is simply not available in the Data Explorer. The editing series of badges comes to mind: there's no way to get an audit of your edits.

Comment: Why would you need an audit of your edits to "game" the badge? 1. Edit every post you can find. 2. Receive badge

Comment: I'm thinking of finding out how many edits you need to do to get the badge rather than getting it naturally or by surprise. I thought I'd read recently that the obscurity was by design to prevent the sort of gaming where one might say "Oh, I only need 20 more edits? I can do that right now!", but I can't find a reference and your point is well taken.